# Creating 2 capture groups from one match

Tags: regex, .net-core

I am working on a regex which parses a log file and puts the desired info in named capture groups. I am using the site regexr.com to test/develop my regex. Part of the data looks like this:

`Text: some stuff\r\n`

Which I have captured using `Text:(?<text>.+?)\\r\\n`

However, some records contain a hex code like this:

`Text: stuff (E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00)`

Note that the code always begins with `(E` and ends with `)`, however the content within is standard hex

I'm having a lot of trouble pulling this match out of the `<text>` capture group, which I believe is caused by a combination of me not knowing what I'm doing and the regex testing website that I'm using not support named capture group backreferences

I tried using `Text:(?<text>.+?(?<code>\k<text>))\\r\\n` but the website says there is an error in my regex

Using a numbered backreference, `Text:(?<text>.+?(?<code>\6))\\r\\n`, no longer causes an error but the capture group is empty. Note that `<text>` is the 6th capture group

Is this even possible, and if it is how can I do it?

**EDIT:** I just discovered that I need to actually provide something for the backreference to match on so `Text:(?<text>.+?(?<code>\6.+?))\\r\\n` is now dumping the full contents (minus the first character) of `<text>` into `<code>` but I'm still having trouble matching just the hex code because my brain is getting fried

Comment: You could make the code group optional and start the match with `(E` will the next closing `)` like `Text:(?<text>.+?(?<code>\(E .+?\))?)\r?\n` https://regex101.com/r/QbNQmo/1 or create another group for hex `Text:(?<text>.+?(?<code>\(E (?<hex>.+?)\))?)\r?\n` this part `.+?` does not exactly match the hex pattern, but it will give you the match. You can further specify that pattern to exactly match it.

Comment: Note you can use `CaptureCollection` in .NET, and regexr (nor regex101) will show you the captures. Use RegexStorm.net/tester. What is the output you need to get?

Comment: Matching the hex values `Text:(?<text>.+?(?<code>\(E (?<hex>[a-fA-F0-9]{2}(?: [a-fA-F0-9]{2})*)\))?)\r?\n` See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=Text%3a%28%3f%3ctext%3e.%2b%3f%28%3f%3ccode%3e%5c%28E+%28%3f%3chex%3e%5ba-fA-F0-9%5d%7b2%7d%28%3f%3a+%5ba-fA-F0-9%5d%7b2%7d%29*%29%5c%29%29%3f%29%5cr%3f%5cn&i=Text%3a+some+stuff%0d%0aText%3a+stuff+%28E+00+00+00+00+00+00+00%29%0d%0a) (click on the Table tab)

Comment: You have `Text: stuff (E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00)` string, what do you need to get?

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to get the full hex code including the E, so everything between ```(``` and ```)```

Comment: Then you need  `Text:(?<text>.+?(?:\((?<parens>[^()]*)\))?)\\r\\n`, see [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=Text%3a%28%3f%3ctext%3e.%2b%3f%28%3f%3a%5c%28%28%3f%3cparens%3e%5b%5e%28%29%5d*%29%5c%29%29%3f%29%5c%5cr%5c%5cn&i=Text%3a+some+stuff%5cr%5cn%0d%0aText%3a+stuff+%28E+00+00+00+00+00+00+00%29%5cr%5cn), click the *Table* tab.

Comment: I tried that one and it didn't work with my data, however I kept working on it and I created ```Text:(?<text>.+?(?:\6(\(E(?<code>.+?)\)?)?))\\r\\n``` now the issue is that this doesn't contain the ```E``` and it matches ```)\r``` at the end

Comment: I'm not sure where to put this but using the regex option ```RegexOption.Singleline``` has helped me. From their documentation "Specifies single-line mode. Changes the meaning of the dot (.) so it matches every character (instead of every character except \n)." I got tired of finding that .net wasn't matching everything that other platforms were and I started trying them out

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this on my own after a few hours...

`Text:(?<text>.+?(?:\6(?:\((?<code>E.+?)\)\\r)?))\\r\\n`

Here's a breakdown

`Text:(?<text>.+?...............................)\\r\\n` matches everything after "Text:" until it finds "\r\n"

`(?:\6.........................)` creates non-capturing group and searches the 6th group

`(?:\((............\)\\r)?` creates non-capturing group and searches for `(XXXX)\r`

`?<code>E.+?)` creates "code" group, refines search to `(EXXX)` and saves

Comment: Better solution that doesn't use any backreferences because regexr.com and the .NET core implementation of regex do not have congruence. ```Text:(?<text>.+?(?:\(E (?<code>.+?)\))?)```